# Logit analysis of binomial response in contigency tables with > 2 categorical predictors

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, categorical-data

Is it true that in binomial count contingency tables that have > 2 predictors of the counts, the MLE estimates of logistic regression parameters can be calculated directly from table values (i.e. calculating empirical proportions and then using them to calculate log odds rations)? I know this is true in 2 x k tables.  Feels true for > 2 predictors if the predictors are independent, but haven't been able to prove it to myself. Does it help if the predictors are independent/orthogonal?  I know in the general case MLE estimates of logistic regression coefficients require an optimization algorithm, but for discrete independent predictors, maybe that's not the case?

For a concrete example, suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
     A B C Y
   1 b c b 0
   2 b a c 0
   3 a a a 0
   4 a a a 1
   5 a a b 0
   6 c c a 0
   ...
5000 a a a 0
```

A, B, and C are what I mean by "dimensions" (sorry, that choice of wording wasn't clear).  They are independent categorical predictors of Y, each with three levels, such that a logistic regression model predicting Y would have no interactions.  I create a 3x3x3 dimensional contingency table as follows (using R syntax).

```
> xtabs(Y ~ ., data = .data)

, , C = a

   B
A     a   b   c
  a 214   7  30
  b 111  56  83
  c  27  27 222

, , C = b

   B
A     a   b   c
  a  66   2  10
  b  32  15  24
  c  13   9  53

, , C = c

   B
A     a   b   c
  a  12   0   1
  b  12   3   6
  c   1   2  18
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "dimensions" being "independent"?  What model do you have in mind, exactly?  Some models have closed-form MLEs and others will not.  And what distinction are you making between "calculated ... from table values" and "an optimization algorithm" (which *a fortiori* depends on exactly the same table values)?

Comment: Thank you whuber, I clarified the wording and added an example